# What would a see through / transparent woman/houri/wife in jannah/paradise look like (as described by Sahih Bukhari)?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, sunnah, jannah

What would a see through / transparent woman look like in jannah/paradise (as described by Sahih Bukhari)?

If they are transparent then you would see their their bones, and the hadith mention this.

> "the marrow of the bones of their legs will be seen through the bones and the flesh."

Sahih al-Bukhari 3245, 3246, [3254](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/64)

And presumably not just their bones but their lungs, if they are transparent.

Also, I've heard that Al Tirmidhi says they are "of white color". How can they be white if they are transparent?